# Difference in output

Tags: oracle

I have two queries and the output is the same. However, the difference is only the sequence in the result. Please help me to understand that.

```
select distinct (count(*) over (partition by job)) as Lists
       ,job 
from emp 
order by LISTS;

1   PRESIDENT 
2   ANALYST 
3   DEVELOPER 
3   MANAGER 
4   CLERK 
4   SALESMAN

select count(*),job 
from emp 
group by job 
order by count(*);

1   PRESIDENT 
2   ANALYST 
3   DEVELOPER 
3   MANAGER 
4   SALESMAN 
4   CLERK
```

In the first output, Clerk is coming first and in the second output, Clerk is coming at the end.

Comment: Unless explicitly specified ordering is random. You're ordering by the count not and not the job so the job order is random when the count is the same. You need to order by job (or some other field) if you want an explicit ordering of the job.

Comment: you should add  a proper data sample for  let us to eval your result ..    ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - you can try the OP's queries on pretty much any table (for example SCOTT.EMP), you will notice the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering of rows with equal keys is not guaranteed - the database is free to deliver those rows in any order it finds convenient. If you want to have consistent ordering you must include the `JOB` field in the `ORDER BY`, so

```
...
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

should do it in both cases.